# React-dates select multiple weeks range

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker, react-dates

I'm currently using [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) to have a DateRangePicker and I would like the user to be able to select multiple weeks at once. I've seen [this way](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DRP%20-%20Calendar%20Props&selectedStory=with%207%20days%20range%20selection&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) to select 7 days at once which is the start of what I want.

I'd like the first click to select the start of the selected week and then be able to highlight and select another week. When the user clicks on this second week, I'd like to set the end date to be the end date of the selected second week.

I'm not limited to `react-dates`, if it's possible / easier with another package, I can use it !!

I hope I was clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the `DateRangePicker` component from `react-dates`, you need these props:

```
<DateRangePicker
...
startDateOffset={day => day.subtract(3, 'days')}
endDateOffset={day => day.add(3, 'days')} />
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lyd5qh

You can use the logic in endDateOffset to point to a method to calculate how many days are left for the end of the week and set it accordingly